# Creating Custom GnuCash Reports with Scheme

Tags: scheme

Are there any resources which show how to create custom GnuCash reports? I don't know the intricacies of Scheme but I do know the basics of Lisp, based on tinkering with Emacs. Is there a site which lays out the API for GnuCash reports, ideally with a little explanation of Scheme as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that their wiki has some information [here](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Custom_Reports).